# how to find from which page my page is being called in web application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

My `ASP.Net application` contains more than 8000 pages. And it has `frame based architecture`. there are some changes I need to implement on couple of pages. By global search I found there are 10 pages I need to implement my change. But I am facing challange in testing my changes. I need to find how to land on to my changed page from running application. If I do global search by page name, It gives me couple of page but most of the places conditional logic is written and when I test condition may not hit. Also some places it is being called through `javascript`.

Is there any easy way to find from where this page is being called?

I am using Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Other than `Request.UrlReferrer` (which has already been suggested by @Waqar) I think you're out of luck - I'm not aware of any VS tool that will be able to do that. Especially if conditional logic is involved in creating the URL's, that would make the job impossibly difficult

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by

```
 if( !IsPostBack )
 {
     if(  Request.UrlReferrer.ToString() != null )
     {
          ViewState["PreviousPageUrl"] = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I guess in order to call UrlReferer() I will have to land to this page right? I am not able to find the flow from where I can land to this page.